# American and British English Spelling

Tags: american-english, british-english, non-native-english

I am a non-native English speaker. I was taught British English in my school days, but now I work in American English. The problem is whenever I try to write English there is a mix up of American and British spellings. I tried to correct this problem by learning the American English spelling whenever I am made aware of a word...but they are too many. Again, if I don't already know  which are the words that have a different American spelling, somewhere it is going to go wrong. Please tell the most effective way to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). What does your research regarding differences between American and British English show?

Comment: I searched this community questions before asking this. There is no previous discussion in this group that solves my query. I searched other websites and at last decided to ask here for further knowledge on any well proven and evidence based method to solve this problem. As this community have well educated people on this subject, so I sought for help. @Helmar thank you once again for providing the links. I shall surely go through them.

Comment: [There's kind of a lot of differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first refer to a source of differences between them, like [Comprehensive* list of American and British spelling differences](http://www.tysto.com/uk-us-spelling-list.html) or wondering 
[Why Do Brits and Americans Spell Words Differently?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/british-and-american-spelling). After a while, you may be able to spot common patterns, until you find that you do not need to resort to such sources.

Honestly, as a non-native speaker, I am not at this point yet.

Comment: Using an American English spell check dictionary can help flag at least some departures from standard American spellings.

Comment: It appears as an horrendously long list. But if you exclude every word that is affected by the rule which changes such as *organise* into *organize*, and *cancelling* into *canceling*, and other of such "rules" - then it becomes a good deal shorter.

Comment: @WS2 Those "rules" are what I called patterns, because I am not sure how generic they are

Comment: +1, for revealing to me just how jumbled my spelling really is as a native English speaker